# What does this pattern mean?

Tags: java

I have a script for automating data analysis. Unfortunately I do not know the format of the input data file. I found this piece of code which is intended to match the format of the file to certain prerequisites before performing the analysis. Can you help with understanding what does the pattern mean?

```
private static final Pattern oldFileHeaderPattern = (newFileHeaderPattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*^\\s*(-1|0|1)\\s+(-1|0|1)\\s*$.*", 40)).compile("\\s*^\\s*(1|0)\\s*$.*", 40)
```

Comment: While I have no answer, this post is an excellent example of why you should avoid using regex if at all possible. If you do use regex, document it well so that future developers don't need to ask StackOverflow what the regex expression means.

Comment: Paste this into regex101, it will explain it. Watch the double slashes

Comment: @AndrewHill I find your statement too generalized. There are cases where regexes are way easier to read than a 30 loc equivalent. Each problem has it's own specific tool. In Unix environments, you deal with regexes every day (it's about thinking, fast and slow).

Comment: @steffen If the regex you're going to use is indeed simpler than an alternative, then by all means implement it - just make sure your code is easily understood by those who need to maintain it in the future. I would recommended this stack-exchange post for those seeking more information: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113237/when-you-should-not-use-regular-expressions

Answer (score 7):

This line is a master class in how not to write Java. Only a true master could pack so many blunders into one line.

1. Can we talk about initializing two constants on one line? Don't do that. Don't ever do that. [`Pattern.compile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile-java.lang.String-int-) is a static method. Chaining static method calls is insanity.

   ```
   private static final Pattern oldFileHeaderPattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*^\\s*(1|0)\\s*$.*", 40);
   private static final Pattern newFileHeaderPattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*^\\s*(-1|0|1)\\s+(-1|0|1)\\s*$.*", 40);
   ```
2. Hard coding the magic number `40` hurts my soul. You're supposed to OR together different named constants if you want multiple flags. Not write out the number.

   ```
   private static final Pattern oldFileHeaderPattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*^\\s*(1|0)\\s*$.*", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
   private static final Pattern newFileHeaderPattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*^\\s*(-1|0|1)\\s+(-1|0|1)\\s*$.*", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
   ```
3. Now let's talk about `\\s*^` and `$.*`. Matching things before and after `^` and `$` anchors is suspect. Normally you put these at the start and end of your regex to require the regex to match a full line and you call it a day.

   Using `*` means they can match zero characters so they don't actually change what's matched. Let's remove them and just use `^` and `$`. That means we can get rid of `DOTALL`, too, since `.` is gone.

   ```
   private static final Pattern oldFileHeaderPattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s*(1|0)\\s*$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
   private static final Pattern newFileHeaderPattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s*(-1|0|1)\\s+(-1|0|1)\\s*$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
   ```

The regexes don't look so bad now, do they? The first one looks for a line consisting of `1` or `0` with optional whitespace on either side. The second one looks for a line with two numbers, each being `-1`, `0`, or `1`.

Comment: Excellent answer, but there's one small mistake: Due to MULTILINE, the `^` matches the notion of 'be at the position immediately following either a newline char or the start of the input, but not the end of the input'. Imagine a string that starts with a few blank lines, and then a '1', and then it ends. If you run .matches() on it, it would fail, whereas with `\\s*^` it would match. If using find() this mostly doesn't matter, but that's not evident from the original paste. The .* after the $ combined with DOTALL means that even if many lines follow, .matches() would match. Both are important.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the intention is to allow blank lines to precede the first pattern. Given the poor quality of the code I doubt the original was carefully covering all edge cases. It'd be better to just call `matcher(...).find()` with the new regexes.